# Где скачать QT 5.4.*?

Tags: qt, qt5

На официальном сайте архива QT нет ссылок на версию Qt 5.4.

Answer (score 1):

Скачать Qt5.4* можно по следующим ссылкам:
Быстро:
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/45ba/5oMfgS6mV

Медленно:
http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.4/*

http://qtmirror.ics.com/pub/qtproject/archive/qt/5.4/5.4.2/qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw491_opengl-5.4.2.exe
http://web.archive.org/web/20150505005146if_/http://anychimirror101.mirrors.tds.net/pub/Qt/archive/qt/5.4/5.4.1/qt-opensource-mac-x64-clang-5.4.1.dmg
http://web.archive.org/web/20151031135202if_/http://anychimirror101.mirrors.tds.net/pub/Qt/archive/qt/5.4/5.4.1/qt-opensource-mac-x64-android-5.4.1.dmg
http://web.archive.org/web/20151210063356if_/http://anychimirror101.mirrors.tds.net/pub/Qt/archive/qt/5.4/5.4.1/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013-5.4.1.exe
http://web.archive.org/web/20151031090731if_/http://anychimirror101.mirrors.tds.net/pub/Qt/archive/qt/5.4/5.4.1/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2010_opengl-5.4.1.exe
http://web.archive.org/web/20151101004416if_/http://anychimirror101.mirrors.tds.net/pub/Qt/archive/qt/5.4/5.4.1/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_opengl-5.4.1.exe

Comment: какому нормальному человеку понадобилась кутэ 5.4?)